# convert not standard notation to list

Tags: python

I have following line of data

```
15 0 42 50 "some text" "" 4 4 "text"
```

I'd like to convert it into dictionary assigning certain names to it:

```
{
    'data1': 15,
    'data2': 0,
    'data3': 42,
    'data4': 50,
    'data5': 'some text',
    'data6': '',
    'data7': 4,
    'data8': 4,
    'data9': 'text',
}
```

How can I do that in Python? Please note double quotes and that sometimes values are empty ("") but even though field should exist in output dictionary.

Comment: Where is your data coming from? Is it a file?

Comment: Is it only number or text enclosed with brackets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have there is basically just space-separated csv data, so you can use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to parse it:

```
data = '15 0 42 50 "some text" "" 4 4 "text"'

import csv
import io

file = io.StringIO(data)  # use io.BytesIO in python 2
reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=' ')
split_data = next(reader)
parsed_data = [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in split_data]

# result: [15, 0, 42, 50, 'some text', '', 4, 4, 'text']
```

If you really need the data as a dict, you can use the following dict comprehension:

```
>>> {'data{}'.format(i): x for i, x in enumerate(parsed_data, 1)}
{'data1': 15, 'data2': 0, 'data3': 42, 'data4': 50, 'data5': 'some text', 'data6': '', 'data7': 4, 'data8': 4, 'data9': 'text'}
```

Comment: This is not working for me, I'm getting: TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str. Maybe because input data comes not from file but from another list? How to fix it?

Comment: @zerocool Use `io.BytesIO` instead of `StringIO` in python 2.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have this that works:

```py
import re

string = '15 0 42 50 "some text" "" 4 4 "text"'

found = []

for match in re.finditer(r'((\d+)|("(.*?)"))', string):
    found.append(match.group(1).strip('"'))

print found
```

Output:

```
['15', '0', '42', '50', 'some text', '', '4', '4', 'text']
```